# What does the caret do in zsh?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

What does the caret `^` do in zsh?
`echo ^` lists the files in the current directory, like `ls`.
I use [grml](https://grml.org/zsh/).

Apparently it is not an alias and `which ^` prints the same as `which $(ls)`.
Also `command -v ^` prints nothing and returns 1.

Can I assume `^` behaves like a variable containing files in current dir?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ PS1='%% ' zsh -f
% print ^
^
% setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
% print ^
...
%
```

So, you must have `EXTENDED_GLOB` enabled, and therefore the `^` is a glob, so after digging through `zshexpn(1)` we find

```
   ^x     (Requires EXTENDED_GLOB to be set.)  Matches anything except the
          pattern x.  This has a higher precedence than `/', so `^foo/bar'
          will  search  directories in `.' except `./foo' for a file named
          `bar'.
```

So "everything except x" matches everything, as you did not exclude anything with a blank x.