# What does mean `^(*.c|*.md)`

Tags: shell, zsh

I am sorry if it is a potential obvious question, but I have no idea what `^()` means in

```bash
ls ^(*.c|*.md)
```

On `zsh`, this argument expands to everything but `*.c` and `*.md` files.

1. What is `^`?
2. What does mean the parenthesis `()` in this context
3. The command `^(*.c||*.md)` also works... Should I use `|` or `||`?

Comment: Related: [What does the caret do in zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355967/what-does-the-caret-do-in-zsh)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. In Zsh, `^` is a [glob operator](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) available when `EXTENDED_GLOB` is set, matching anything *except* the following pattern.
2. The parentheses group a pattern; this is useful in particular with disjunctions (`|`) where parentheses are required so that the disjunction isn’t interpreted as a pipe.
3. `^(*.c||*.md)` means “anything except files matching `*.c`, or files with an empty name, or files matching `*.md`”; the empty name is useless, so you should use `|`. You could also write it `^*.(c|md)` to avoid repeating the `*.`.

You should also use the `--` option delimiter for `ls` as otherwise if any of the file names started with `-`, they'd be treated as options by `ls`.

If you don't intend `ls` to list the contents of those files resulting from that glob expansion that happen to be of type *directory*, you should use the `-d` option. Or just use the `print` builtin to print those file names; `ls` would only be useful with options like `-l` to get metadata information from those files.

```
ls -ld -- ^*.(md|c)
print -rC1 -- ^*.(md|c)(N)
```

Here with the file names `print`ed `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn.  `N` glob qualifier for `NULL_GLOB` to avoid an error if no matching file is found (and get no output from `print`).